# Check if date is between hours interval or week-end. If not, calculate how many hours left until available hour

Tags: php

I need some help if someone would be so kind.
For 2 days I'm squeezing my brains trying to make a script which will inform visitors about tech support online status.

The office hours are from 10AM to 18:30PM.
If the visitor is in this hours interval, it's easy, the message will be "online".
If he's out of the office hours, I need to display the number of hours remaining until tech support will be available and if week-ends or Friday evening, another message will be displayed.

This is my script and I don't really figure where I'm wrong.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

```
$date2 = date("l", time());
$date3 = strtolower($date2);

$now = (int) date('Hi');
$time1 = 1000;
$time2 = 1830;

$currentTime = time();
if (date("G") >= 19 || (date("G") == 18 && date("i") > 00)) {
$datetime1 = 10 * 3600 + strtotime("now") + (24 - date("G")) * 3600 + 
(60 - date("i")) * 60;
} else {
$datetime1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d") + " 10:00:00");
}

$interval = abs($datetime1 - $currentTime);
$hours = round($interval / 3600);

if (($date3 == "saturday") || ($date3 == "sunday")) {
$status = '<span style="color:#909090;">
OFFLINE. We\'ll be available on Monday    morning.</span>';
} elseif ($date3 == "friday") {
if ($now > $time2) {
    $status = '<span style="color:#909090;">
OFFLINE. We\'ll be available on     Monday morning.</span>';
} elseif ($now < $time1) {
    $status = '
<span style="color:#909090;">OFFLINE. We\'ll be online in about ' . $hours . ' hours.  </span>';
} else {
    $status = '<span style="color:#32a300;">ONLINE, solving customer issues. </span>';
}
} else {
if ($now > $time1 && $now < $time2) {
    $status = '<span style="color:#32a300;">ONLINE, solving customer issues.</span>';
} else {
    $status = '<span style="color:#909090;">OFFLINE. We\'ll be become online in about ' . $hours . ' hours.</span>';
}
}

echo $status;
```

Comment: Can you say what part of your script isn't working?  That will help others answer your question faster.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered refactoring your code by using the `DateTime` class? It's compatible with PHP 5.2+ and it's usually the recommended way of dealing with dates in PHP.

```
$start_date = new \DateTime('today 10:00');
$end_date = new \DateTime('today 18:30');
$now = new \DateTime();

if ($now->format('N') >= 6) {
    // weekend
}

if ($start_date <= $now && $now < $end_date) {
    // office hours
} else {
    // closing hours
}
```

The above example is much easier to read/understand/debug and it spares you the trouble of manually doing all the calculations and date conversions yourself.

The `Datetime` class will also allow you to easily calculate the time difference between 2 individual dates:

```
$opening_time = new \DateTime('tomorrow 10:00');
$now = new \DateTime();

$time_difference = $now->diff($opening_time);
$remaining_time = $time_difference->format('%h hours, %i minutes');

echo $remaining_time . ' until we will open.';
```

This should output something like `13 hours, 15 minutes until we will open.".

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, but I also need to check if week-end

Comment: I've also included a weekend check in my answer. `$now->format('N')` returns a number from 1-7. 6 and 7 are equivalent to Saturday and Sunday, which means that if the returned number is higher than 6 then the current date is part of a weekend.